# What experiences the force of flux pinning?

Tags: forces, magnetic-fields, superconductivity

https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.06329

Flux pinning produces a significant force density (according to this paper in the $30 \ GN/m^3$ range).

Does the magnet experience the counter force given off? Or does both the superconductor & magnetic component experience no force? (because it's cancelled out).

https://youtu.be/uR35VTWmdYg

Comment: What is 30GN\m³ ? Do you mean $30 \ GN/m^3 ?$

Comment: What is the linked youtube video supposed to add to the question?

Comment: @brendandarrer according to the paper I posted the force density of flux pinning is in the order of 30 GigaNewtons per cubic meter.

Comment: @quillio I put it in to showcase the force transfer occuring when the magnet & superconductor are flux pinned in tandem. (Specifically the part when he puts it on a scale)(he has another video where he has the lifting capabilities).